# Как сделать обработчик onclick на строку таблицы tr после добавления этой строки путем ajax .append?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть таблица которая частично создается

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><b>#</b></td>
        <td><b>Фамилия</b></td>
        <td><b>Имя</b></td>
        <td><b>Отчество</b></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

И есть javascript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DataTable",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $.each(data, function (i) {
                    $("#table").append("<tr id = '" + (i+1) + "'> <td>" + (i + 1) + "</td> <td>" + data[i].Surname + "</td> <td>" + data[i].Name + "</td> <td>" + data[i].Lastname + "</td> </tr>");
                    i++;
                });
            }
        });
        $('table tr').bind('click', function () {
            alert("dsfsdf111111");
        });

    });

    $('table tr').bind('click', function () {
        alert("dsfsdf111111");
    });

    $("#4").on("click", function () {
        alert("dsfsdf");
    });

</script>
```

Когда я нажимаю на созданные `append` строки - ничего не происходит, а когда нажимаю на строку созданную изначально `html` кодом то функция `alert` вызывается. 
Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на созданные строки срабатывал обработчик события?

И каким образом можно указать чтобы при нажатии на идентификатор от 1 до .... вызывался обработчик `onclick`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте такой подход:

```
$(document).on("click", '.mylink', function(event) { 
    alert("new link clicked!");
});
```

(с) [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598213/how-to-bind-events-on-ajax-loaded-content#16598231)

Comment: А как сделать чтобы для каждой строки вызывался соответствующий onclick?

Comment: Вы про замену `.mylink` на `table tr`? *...ради бога...*

Comment: Это понятно, я про добавление $('Идентификатор от 1 до ...').bind('click', function () {
        alert("dsfsdf111111");
    }); Чтобы мне не писать 100500 onclick ?